# Am I missing something with stereo calibration?

Tags: opencv, camera-calibration

I am trying the stereo_calib example and it fails with garbage output. For instance:

[image]

However, it is finding corners in my images...

[image]

My xml file and images are all here:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=12-5jBN7FK-LO6SLb4r3YYkrOnP7f_xmG

What am I doing wrong? I first tried printing a pattern on a sheet of paper, then thought ok that must be too wavy or something, so had this printed on foam board. But no dice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(we chatted on a side channel, so this is to the benefit of the rest of the world)*

tl;dr: hold the board **very** still or get a camera with global shutter.

Rolling shutter (see [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dNVtMmLlnoE) and [there](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mQ0hS7l9ckY)), an attribute of most webcam sensors, many camcorder sensors, and some industrial image sensors, will distort objects that are moving. If you've moved the board even just a little during a frame capture (visible in files right19/right20), it will be captured with distortion. That will affect everything you do with the picture, starting with intrinsic calibration.

To give a sense of scale for the distortions: assuming a 30 FPS video stream, the worst case rolling shutter lag is 33 ms. A pedestrian travels 40-50 mm in that time. If your hands are moving slightly, you can maybe expect a tenth of that, which is still **a lot** in proportion to the square sizes most people use.

Another source of trouble is printers. If you've printed your checkerboard pattern, make sure to measure the width and height of your squares. they might be slightly rectangular. It's also a good idea to make sure the pattern is quite flat, not bent.